# Deploying Django To Heroku gives server error (500)

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

please i know this question has been asked several times but with those answers i still haven't solved it.I turned debug to False in my settings.py file (but before I turned it to false, everything was working perfectly) and when I ran git push heroku master and went to my website,I got an error saying Server Error (500). please i need help.

please here is my settings.py

```
import os
import django_heroku 

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'KEY'

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app.apps.AppConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'




STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

here is my wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)]
```

here is my procfile

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi
```

here is also the log

```
2020-04-03T23:19:17.048794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=f256ae96-58b7-4b3d-8918-ebe9c5039a8f fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=168ms status=200 bytes=1481 protocol=https
    2020-04-03T23:26:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-03T23:27:08.496196+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
    2020-04-03T23:27:08.509916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
    2020-04-03T23:27:08.255092+00:00 app[api]: Release v30 created by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-03T23:27:08.255092+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9f5b04c4 by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-03T23:27:10.115103+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2020-04-03T23:27:10.115132+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:10 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
    2020-04-03T23:27:10.115294+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:10 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-04-03T23:27:10.173519+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:10 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
    2020-04-03T23:27:10.622863+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-04-03T23:27:17.686321+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
    2020-04-03T23:27:17.687425+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:23382 (4)
    2020-04-03T23:27:17.687634+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2020-04-03T23:27:17.693114+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:17 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
    2020-04-03T23:27:17.782253+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:17 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
    2020-04-03T23:27:17.788392+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-03 23:27:17 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
    2020-04-03T23:27:19.072911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2020-04-03T23:27:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2020-04-03T23:28:26.147174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=cbbed72e-d637-49b6-919b-e4943769f77f fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=87ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
    2020-04-04T00:05:27.732399+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2020-04-04T00:05:27.736113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2020-04-04T00:05:28.987837+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:05:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-04-04T00:05:28.989531+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:05:28 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
    2020-04-04T00:05:28.989532+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:05:28 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
    2020-04-04T00:05:29.023769+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:05:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2020-04-04T00:05:29.128350+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:05:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-04-04T00:09:02.170269+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:09:12.765017+00:00 heroku[run.5125]: State changed from starting to up
    2020-04-04T00:09:20.615792+00:00 heroku[run.5125]: State changed from up to complete
    2020-04-04T00:22:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:22:59.647746+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2020-04-04T00:22:59.473272+00:00 app[api]: Release v31 created by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:22:59.473272+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7c246a8d by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:23:10.251493+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:23:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
    2020-04-04T00:23:10.252451+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:23:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:45015 (4)
    2020-04-04T00:23:10.252653+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:23:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2020-04-04T00:23:10.258555+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:23:10 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
    2020-04-04T00:23:10.335781+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:23:10 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
    2020-04-04T00:23:10.420903+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:23:10 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
    2020-04-04T00:23:11.515288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2020-04-04T00:23:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2020-04-04T00:23:53.831213+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=2258d8bf-2dc0-4db3-8300-0983c37a1a77 fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=124ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
    2020-04-04T00:28:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:29:08.695619+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
    2020-04-04T00:29:08.709107+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
    2020-04-04T00:29:08.208818+00:00 app[api]: Release v32 created by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:29:08.208818+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 437a88e8 by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:29:10.056927+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:10 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-04-04T00:29:10.057695+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:10 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)
    2020-04-04T00:29:10.057955+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:10 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
    2020-04-04T00:29:10.062903+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2020-04-04T00:29:10.173052+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-04-04T00:29:18.767300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2020-04-04T00:29:18.336129+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
    2020-04-04T00:29:18.336709+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:35013 (4)
    2020-04-04T00:29:18.336834+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2020-04-04T00:29:18.340984+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:18 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
    2020-04-04T00:29:18.343711+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:18 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
    2020-04-04T00:29:18.355032+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:29:18 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
    2020-04-04T00:29:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2020-04-04T00:31:24.032205+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=d6e1891a-019b-4661-a569-ae81a9667d42 fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=117ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
    2020-04-04T00:45:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:46:30.645452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
    2020-04-04T00:46:30.662471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
    2020-04-04T00:46:30.460193+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2b709fc5 by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:46:30.460193+00:00 app[api]: Release v33 created by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T00:46:32.100078+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2020-04-04T00:46:32.100099+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:32 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
    2020-04-04T00:46:32.101937+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:32 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
    2020-04-04T00:46:32.119891+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-04-04T00:46:32.402798+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-04-04T00:46:39.233656+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
    2020-04-04T00:46:39.234155+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:25432 (4)
    2020-04-04T00:46:39.234253+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2020-04-04T00:46:39.238140+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:39 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
    2020-04-04T00:46:39.284338+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:39 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
    2020-04-04T00:46:39.302491+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 00:46:39 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
    2020-04-04T00:46:39.765709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2020-04-04T00:46:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2020-04-04T00:58:08.573371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=2ff694e8-2154-4848-89e0-8710f1420da8 fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=66ms status=302 bytes=346 protocol=https
    2020-04-04T00:58:18.218322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/login/?next=/admin/" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=8af49c95-167c-4f33-9bbe-d38241a7055f fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=171ms status=200 bytes=2333 protocol=https
    2020-04-04T01:08:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T01:09:09.416125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
    2020-04-04T01:09:09.433681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
    2020-04-04T01:09:08.838530+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 87fb8ce7 by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T01:09:08.838530+00:00 app[api]: Release v34 created by user kwesijoe1000@gmail.com
    2020-04-04T01:09:10.587534+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:10 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
    2020-04-04T01:09:10.587604+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:10 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-04-04T01:09:10.587612+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2020-04-04T01:09:10.588489+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:10 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
    2020-04-04T01:09:10.796189+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-04-04T01:09:17.552127+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
    2020-04-04T01:09:17.552717+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:36536 (4)
    2020-04-04T01:09:17.552842+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2020-04-04T01:09:17.556796+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:17 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
    2020-04-04T01:09:17.564440+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:17 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
    2020-04-04T01:09:17.651369+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-04 01:09:17 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
    2020-04-04T01:09:18.052024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2020-04-04T01:09:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2020-04-04T01:28:27.901481+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admin/login/?next=/admin/" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=ec4548a8-b687-481a-ae4c-7eb21b547dad fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=711ms status=200 bytes=2492 protocol=https
    2020-04-04T01:28:28.246458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.50d75e48e0a3.woff" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=f645fc45-36cf-4f7b-aa86-cabb0cafec2b fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=86464 protocol=https
    2020-04-04T01:28:28.174209+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=jimtec.herokuapp.com request_id=3aa4131e-a894-4a51-bb36-cab00f19bc66 fwd="102.176.94.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=79ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
```

Comment: When you set `DEBUG=False` what error you were getting?

Comment: please i get Server Error (500).

Comment: You say it's showing Error 500 that means there is some error in Django so, set  `DUBUG = True` and identify the error

Comment: when i set it to true, everything works well

Answer (score 0):

WhiteNoise is mostly the issue, so if you are not religious about, disable it:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

to (in this order):

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

also remove

```
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)]
```

Comment: please its still got an error saying Server Error (500)